# Puedo hacer un JOIN aquí

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Necesito hacer un JOIN aquí, es posible? necesito acceder a la tabla de users con la columna de `id_cliente` que hay en la tabla de `orders`.

```
$data = Order::select('created_at', DB::raw('SUM(total + envio) as total'))
->where('id_cliente', $id)
->groupBy('ticket', 'created_at')->get();
```

Aquí no he se como hacer un `INNER` necesito el total, para la gráfica, y donde esta `->where('id_cliente', $id)` tiene que ser `->where('orders.slug', $slug)

Parece que me funciona así:

```
$data = Order::
       join('users', 'orders.id_cliente', '=', 'users.id')
       ->select('orders.created_at', DB::raw('SUM(total + envio) as total'))
       ->where('users.slug', $slug)
       ->groupBy('orders.ticket', 'orders.created_at')->get();
```

Comment: Has intentado algo al respecto?

Comment: Si que he probado, te lo pongo espera @BetaM

Comment: Espera que me he hecho un lio, esa consulta no es, tengo que remirar algo antes de poner esto

Comment: Ahora @BetaM ya he puesto la query correcta

Comment: Si ya encontraste la solución, entonces va como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución la hice así:

```
$data = Order::
       join('users', 'orders.id_cliente', '=', 'users.id')
       ->select('orders.created_at', DB::raw('SUM(total + envio) as total'))
       ->where('users.slug', $slug)
       ->groupBy('orders.ticket', 'orders.created_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Claro que puedes, solo sigue bien la sintaxis y ya.
Te dejo un ejemplo.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins